# QMetaObject::invokeMethod does not take a non const argument

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing a project with Qt where in invoke method runs on a seperate thread and called from main thread.
If I pass a `QByteArray` as const it builds and runs.
However if I remove the const it builds but terminates when I try to run it,
and throws an assert `Q_ASSERT(b)`.

Why is it getting terminated?

I have to append some data into `QByteArray`.

```
const bool b = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_thread, "calculateSpectrum",
                              Qt::AutoConnection,
                              Q_ARG(QByteArray, buffer),
                              Q_ARG(int, format.frequency()),
                              Q_ARG(int, bytesPerSample),
                              Q_ARG(qint64, dataLength));
    Q_ASSERT(b);
    Q_UNUSED(b) // suppress warnings in release builds
```

Comment: What's the signature of `calculateSpectrum`? Are you expecting `buffer` to be modified in the caller?

Comment: yes i am expecting to change buffer and signature is spectrumanalyser(qbytearray buffer,int frequency, int bytes , qint64 datalength)

Comment: Please edit the correct method's signature into your question (use the "edit" link under the tags).

Comment: If you have a hardcoded method name as in your example, you don't need dynamic invocation. Calling across threads can be done safely by emitting a signal.

Comment: Were you able to modify `buffer` after passing it as `const`? Would you provide the rest of the code (or an example) for those of us that come across this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

basically the signature of QMetaobject::invokemethod is...

```
bool    invokeMethod ( QObject * obj, const char * member, Qt::ConnectionType type, QGenericReturnArgument ret, QGenericArgument val0 = QGenericArgument( 0 ), QGenericArgument val1 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val2 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val3 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val4 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val5 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val6 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val7 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val8 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val9 = QGenericArgument() );
```

now in this we are using the Q_ARG macro whose syntax is..

```
QGenericArgument    Q_ARG ( Type, const Type & value )
```

which requires a const parameter.

Now when u remove this const parameter the condition becomes false and it will throw an assert at runtime.